# How to link code with catkin?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having trouble linking code with catkin have the following file structure:

```
mypackage/
|src/
    | ros_node.cpp
|lib/
    | library.c
|include/
    | library.h
```

ros_node.cpp includes library.h and my CMakelist has the following for building:

```
add_library(library lib/library.c)
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(ros_node src/ros_node.cpp)    
add_dependencies(ros_node ros_node_generate_messages_cpp)
target_link_libraries(ros_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES} library)
```

This fails when linking the library to the ROS node. Anyone able to point me in the right direction for properly linking with ROS?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/96896/how-to-link-code-with-catkin?/) by [oars](https://answers.ros.org/users/4512/oars/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2013-11-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved it. I was missing `link_directories(lib)`.

---

Originally posted by [oars](https://answers.ros.org/users/4512/oars/) with karma: 48 on 2013-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1